# Vue convert to SSR

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering

I have an existing VUE 3 app written in typescript, how I can convert it to SSR?

project structure

```
 1. node_modules
 2. public
 3. src
    - assets
    - components
    - core
    - layout
    - router
    - store
    - views
    - App.vue
    - main.ts
 5. .browserslistrc
 6. .env
 7. .eslintignore
 8. .eslintrc.js
 9. .prettierrc
 10. package.json
 11. tsconfig.json
 12. vue.config.js
 13. webpack-rtl.config.js
```

Could you please help me with that, I tried many ways but no one worked.